# Using one keyboard for a two player game

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

I'm having some problems with a game I'm making as a project. It consists mainly of two players using the WASD to move and E to stop and the second player uses de arrow keys to move and SHIFT to stop.

The main problem I have is when both players move the rockets at the same time, when one rocket turns to the left or right the other player can't move at all to the sides or it moves forward but slowly and with the same issue, it can't move to the left or right.

Any idea on what could be the issue with the controls or anything I'm not considering in my code?

This are some of the classes for the game:

GameDraw Class, it has the movements of the players and draw the rockets.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

class GameDraw extends JComponent{
            static Jugador rocket1 = new Jugador();
            static Jugador rocket2 = new Jugador();
            int width = GUI.width;
            int height = GUI.height;

            public GameDraw() {}

            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D graphicsSet = (Graphics2D) g;
                AffineTransform id = new AffineTransform();
                AffineTransform id2 = new AffineTransform();
                graphicsSet.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                graphicsSet.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                graphicsSet.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                graphicsSet.setPaint(Color.blue);

                //Player 1 Controls//
                if(GUI.keyHeld_D == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.D) {
                    rocket1.increaseRotAngle();
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_A == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.A) {
                    rocket1.decreaseRotAngle();
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_W == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.W) {
                    rocket1.setMovingAngle(rocket1.getRotationAngle());
                    rocket1.increaseXVel(rocket1.rocketXMoveAngle(rocket1.getMovingAngle())*0.1);
                    rocket1.increaseYVel(rocket1.rocketYMoveAngle(rocket1.getMovingAngle())*0.1);   
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_S == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.S) {
                    rocket1.setMovingAngle(rocket1.getRotationAngle());
                    rocket1.decreaseXVel(rocket1.rocketXMoveAngle(rocket1.getMovingAngle())*0.1);
                    rocket1.decreaseYVel(rocket1.rocketYMoveAngle(rocket1.getMovingAngle())*0.1);
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_E == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.E) {
                    rocket1.stopRocket();
                }


                //Player 2 Controls//
                if(GUI.keyHeld_RIGHT == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.RIGHT) {
                    rocket2.increaseRotAngle();
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_LEFT == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.LEFT) {
                    rocket2.decreaseRotAngle();
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_UP == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.UP) {
                    rocket2.setMovingAngle(rocket2.getRotationAngle());
                    rocket2.increaseXVel(rocket2.rocketXMoveAngle(rocket2.getMovingAngle())*0.1);
                    rocket2.increaseYVel(rocket2.rocketYMoveAngle(rocket2.getMovingAngle())*0.1);   
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_DOWN == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.DOWN) {
                    rocket2.setMovingAngle(rocket2.getRotationAngle());
                    rocket2.decreaseXVel(rocket2.rocketXMoveAngle(rocket2.getMovingAngle())*0.1);
                    rocket2.decreaseYVel(rocket2.rocketYMoveAngle(rocket2.getMovingAngle())*0.1);
                }
                else if(GUI.keyHeld_SHIFT == true && GUI.keyHeldCode == Controls.SHIFT) {
                    rocket2.stopRocket();
                }

                rocket1.movement();
                graphicsSet.setTransform(id);
                graphicsSet.translate(rocket1.getXCenter(), rocket1.getYCenter());
                graphicsSet.rotate(Math.toRadians(rocket1.getRotationAngle()));
                graphicsSet.draw(rocket1);

                rocket2.movement();
                graphicsSet.setTransform(id2);
                graphicsSet.translate(rocket2.getXCenter(), rocket2.getYCenter());
                graphicsSet.rotate(Math.toRadians(rocket2.getRotationAngle()));
                graphicsSet.draw(rocket2);
            }
        }
```

GUI Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public static int width = 1000;
    public static int height = 600;
    public static boolean keyHeld_W = false, keyHeld_A = false, keyHeld_S = false, keyHeld_D = false, keyHeld_E = false, keyHeld_UP = false, keyHeld_LEFT = false, keyHeld_DOWN = false, keyHeld_RIGHT = false, keyHeld_SHIFT = false;
    public static int keyHeldCode;

    public GUI() {
        this.setTitle("ROCKET FOOTBALL");
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                keyHeldCode = keyCode;
                //Player 1 Controls//
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.W) {
                    Jugador.interaction_W = true;
                    keyHeld_W = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.A) {
                    Jugador.interaction_A = true;
                    keyHeld_A = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.S) {
                    Jugador.interaction_S = true;
                    keyHeld_S = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.D) {
                    Jugador.interaction_D = true;
                    keyHeld_D = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.E) {
                    Jugador.interaction_E = true;
                    keyHeld_E = true;
                }

                    //Player 2 Controls//
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.UP) {
                    Jugador.interaction_UP = true;
                    keyHeld_UP = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.LEFT) {
                    Jugador.interaction_LEFT = true;
                    keyHeld_LEFT = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.DOWN) {
                    Jugador.interaction_DOWN = true;
                    keyHeld_DOWN = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.RIGHT) {
                    Jugador.interaction_RIGHT = true;
                    keyHeld_RIGHT = true;
                }
                if(keyHeldCode == Controls.SHIFT) {
                    Jugador.interaction_SHIFT = true;
                    keyHeld_SHIFT = true;
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                //Player 1//
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.W) {
                        keyHeld_W = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.A) {
                        keyHeld_A = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.S) {
                        keyHeld_S = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.D) {
                        keyHeld_D = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.E) {
                        keyHeld_E = false;
                    }

                    //Player 2//
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.UP) {
                        keyHeld_UP = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.LEFT) {
                        keyHeld_LEFT = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.DOWN) {
                        keyHeld_DOWN = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.RIGHT) {
                        keyHeld_RIGHT = false;
                    }
                    if(keyHeldCode == Controls.SHIFT) {
                        keyHeld_SHIFT = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        GameDraw gamePanel = new GameDraw();
        this.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
        ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RepaintTheBoard(this), 0L,20L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a keyboard rollover issue. If you are using a generic brand of keyboard, it may only support up to 3 button presses simultaneously.

Comment: I'm using a laptop keyboard and a normal membrane keyboard when testing on my desktop. I read somewhere about that issue with the keyboard and also on using keybindings but i don't know how to implement it correctly on my code. :/

Answer (score 0):

> when one rocket turns to the left or right the other player can't move at all

KeyEvents can only be generated for the last key pressed. So basically you need to keep track of a key as it is pressed and you need to use a Timer to schedule the animation. So every time the Timer fires, you check which keys are currently pressed and invoke the appropriate action.

> also on using keybindings

Yes, key bindings is the preferred approach as it removes focus issues.

Check out the `KeyboardAnimation` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). The example uses the 4 arrow keys for one player and WASD for the other player with a couple of differences:

1. You can hold two keys down at the same time to have diagonal movement
2. You need to release the keys to stop the motion